# Why is there no increment to change the case in my switch statement?

Tags: javascript, dom, switch-statement

What I intend to achieve with this code is that on click of the "Click Me!" button it should increment num +1 so it would change then the case. Eg. from case 0 to case 1 in the switch statement. But all I get back is undefined. I tried to have the switch statement and the num++ function on their own but didn't work as well. Any help is appreciated towards the solution.

```js
var btn=document.querySelector("button")
    var text="test"
    var num

function changeCase () {
  btn.addEventListener(onclick, function (){num++})
  switch (num) {
  case 0:
    text = "Off";
    break;
  case 1:
    text = "On";
    break;
  default:
    text = "No value found";
  }
}

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div>
      <button onclick="changeCase()">Click Me!</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have an undeclared variable - `onclick` - in your code, also, this should probably be replaced by `'click'`. Were there any errors reported in your browser's dev tools/console.

Comment: You're also attaching a new handler to increment `num` every time the button is clicked.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica - The irritating part about it is that there's no error from that...because `onclick` isn't undeclared there, it's a default global variable in browsers (because `window` has `onclick`, and all `window` properties are global variables). Fun fun fun...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know that browsers will (almost certainly) never remove that "feature," to avoid breaking legacy code, but there some historical features that I find truly icky.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica - Big time. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- You're not doing anything with `text` after changing it in `changeCase`. You've only used it **once**, on page load.
- You're using both an `onclick` attribute and then also, when that's clicked, you're trying to add an event listener for `click`.
- You're using `onclick` as an identifier in the `addEventListener` call, but you wanted `"click"` as a string (and no "on").
- You probably want to set an initial value for `num`, instead of leting it default to the value `undefined`. If you do `num++` when `num` has `undefined` in it, you'll get `NaN`, which doesn't match any of your cases.

To fix it:

- Don't use `onclick` attributes, use `addEventListener`.
- Use `text` after changing it.
- Add the value for `num`.

Here's an example:

```js
var btn=document.querySelector("button");
var text="test";
var num = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function (){
    num++;
    changeCase();
});

function changeCase () {
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            text = "Off";
            break;
        case 1:
            text = "On";
            break;
        default:
            text = "No value found";
            break;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

changeCase();
```

```html
<h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div>
      <button>Click Me!</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm. I'm still very new to Javascript and not always sure I got the concept right. Can you perhaps explain to me why you put changeCase() at the bottom and what it is doing?

Comment: @ThugAngel - That's so it fills in the `demo` element with the initial value ("Off"). If I didn't have the call there, you wouldn't have anything in the element until you clicked the button. Happy coding!